# find cheapest path through array (recursion)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm currently working on recursion and i keep getting stuck at this question:

Find the cheapest path through an array using recursion. for example, if i had an array [0,1,3,4,1] i start at the value 0. Now i have 2 options i could jump to index 2 or just move to index 1.In this case i would jump right to index 2 (value 3) then jump to index 4 (value 1) because 3+1= 4 and that would be the cheapest way through the array.

I've tried to compare the move index value with the jump index value and see which is smallest but in this case that would not work because if i compare move value (1) with jump value (3), 1 is smallest and my program would take that as the correct path when in reality it is not and the 3 was a better option.

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Explain your rational for "jumping" to those indices.

Comment: sorry. For this we can only jump or move. Jump = 2 spaces ahead and move = 1 space ahead. So in order to find the cheapest path i would jump to value 3 then jump to value 1. all other possibilities are more "expensive".

Comment: It's still not making sense.  You should describe what part the recursion plays here, as well as what rationale you use to jump (is it the value in the array, like I'm thinking?).

Comment: The object of the game is to move from the first column to the last column in the lowest total cost. You always start the game in the first column and have two types of moves: You can either
move to the adjacent column or jump over the adjacent column to land two columns over. The cost of the game is the sum of the costs of the visited columns. So this is where a recursive solution comes into play. How does one decide which path to take?

Comment: @Makoto he means that from a certain index `i` in the array he can go to either index  `i+1` or `i+2` and in this way he has to reach the end of the array. For each index that he visits, he adds its value. The goal is to find a path through the array with a minimum total value.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using dynamic programming.Let's say we create one array dp, in which dp[i] represents min cost to reach at position i.
We can fill this array upto size of input using following:

```
for(i=1;i<=len;i++) 
   //we can reach at current position either by i-1 or by i-2
   //choose one which gives minimum cost and +arr[i] cost of current position
   dp[i] = min(dp[i-1],dp[i-2])+arr[i]
```

we can reach at ith position either by previous position by taking one move or by i-2 by taking a jump of 2.So in this way you can find the minimum cost to reach the final position.So dp[len] will be your minimum cost to reach at last position.
There is one similar problem [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ways-reach-nth-stair/)

Comment: You can solve this problem using recursion also but it will take exponential time.That's why I have written one O(n) approach.

Comment: definitely appreciate the O(n) approach but i'm currently reading a chapter on recursion and this question has stumped me fore a long time.

Comment: Then you can make function as 
`int recurse(vector<int>&arr, int cur, int cost)`
where cur represents from which position you need to reach to end and base condition will be whether cur == len and cost will be the minimum cost to reach cur position.

Comment: Here is live demo in C++
http://cpp.sh/3zvg You can make similar program in java.