# Cheapest cost through an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, recursion, theory

## Question

Given an array of length[N] you must start at array[0] and traverse through to the end.  You are allowed to to move one position or two i.e. array[0] -> array[1] or array[0] -> array[2] depending on which sum of numbers are lower.  This will repeat all the way to the end and must include array[N].

[1, 10, 3, 8, 4]
Cheapest way to navigate is = 8 via array[0] + array[2] + array[4]

## My current solution:

```
int totalCost = 0
totalCost += array[0]
int i = 1;
while (i < array.length)
{
    if (i + 1 < array.length)
    {
        int sum1 = totalCost + array[i];
        int sum2 = totalCost + array[i + 1];
        if (sum1 < sum2)
        {
            totalCost += array[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            totalCost += array[i + 1];
            i += 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        totalCost += array[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

This seems to work for most arrays...the issue comes into play where if an early jump results in a bigger number but allows for a better jump further through the array ultimately resulting in a lower number.  I have no clue how to approach that.

Comment: Well how would you determine that a longer jump at an earlier time would have led to lower overall cost? Only by actually finishing the entire route, right?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201787/find-cheapest-path-through-array-recursion?rq=1 ?

Comment: can you have negative number in the array?

Comment: @RomanPekar I do not believe so, the only thing I know is I was not allowed to sort the array.

Comment: @UnholySheep I agree, I will have to move through the entire array to see all possible combinations.  I have thought about similar problems such as factorials to determine total number of possible combinations, but that is not quite the same as this.  Also I was thinking of having a reference array of all the possible sums.  Still not sure how I would account for all possible options.

Comment: @JayGuyll if you are actually moving into the area of AI you could think about using e.g.: [Genetic Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) (and there's a few other options as well) - are you sure you need to perform this level of cost optimization?

Comment: @UnholySheep I am doubtful it is meant to be that complicated.  If the dilemma I am finding is beyond the basic problem, then maybe I am just over thinking it.  I was thinking it might be solvable with a recursive function that somehow looped through the entire array and then made choices based on future sums of two numbers but the more I rack my brain on this...your AI comment makes more sense.

Comment: @JayGuyll that's why I asked if you really need to perform optimization - the simple algorithm will work for most cases and should be good enough (although it is good to know about its limitations and edge cases).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not working, because you try to decide on the next move when you are at some element. Point is, you can't generally decide on your next move until you know all element values up to the second element from the end of array.

Not only in computer science but generally it is easier to look into the past and learn than to look into the future and predict. So whenever a problem or sub-problem can be solved from historic data, don't try to solve it with future expectations.

Now, lets look how this can be applied to your problem.

If you are at position `i` in your array, what you do is trying to predict the right way by looking at the possible next steps and deciding on one of them, this is not working reliably. So lets instead suppose you are at position `i` and you don't want to know where to go next but instead you ask *"What is the best (cost efficient) way to reach the current position and how much does it cost?"*.

For the first position `i=0`, this is trivial. You reach this position by starting the algorithm and the cost equals the value of `a[0]`.

For the second position `i=1`, it is also trivial. You can move in steps of 1 (small step) or 2 (big step), but in this specific case, only a small step is possible, so you reach `i=1` by comming from position `i=0` and the cost equals the cost of reaching `i=0` plus the value of position `i=1`.

For all following positions `i>1`, a decision needs to be made, whether the current position is reached by going a small step or a big step. If the current position is reached by a small step, its cost is calculated as the cost of reaching `i-1` plus the value of position `i`. Other case, if the current position is reached by a big step, its cost is calculated as the cost of reaching `i-2` plus the value of position `i`. In order to reach position `i` with the lowest cost, decide between small and big step by comparing their associated cost and chosing the minimum.

When the end of the array is reached, the cost and steps of reaching each position will be computed and the cost of reaching the last position can be returned as a result.

If you only need the minimum cost and not the actual path, then the following should work (c-related pseudo code):

```
costs[array.size] = { 0 };

for (i = 0; i < array.size; ++i)
{
    if (i > 1) costs[i] = array[i] + min(costs[i-1], costs[i-2]);
    else if (i > 0) costs[i] = array[i] + costs[i-1];
    else costs[i] = array[i];
}

result = costs[array.size - 1];
```

It basically says: reaching a point `i` can be done by comming from the previous point or from 2 points before. If the cost for the two previous points is already computed, the decision is as easy as taking the minimum of the two previous point costs and adding the current point cost.

Instead of an array with all sub-costs, you could even do with a total of 3 variables (discard sub-costs that represent indices below `i-2`), but then the path can't be re-constructed from the sub-costs.

Comment: This seems like it doesn't account for the possibility of being allowed to move to array[i + 1] if the cost is lower.  Am I mistaken and reading this wrong?

Comment: @JayGuyll I think you are reading this wrong. This approach is generally not trying to predict anything (`i + 1`) but it is computing the cost for the current point by accessing previous costs (`i - 1` and `i - 2`). The `i - 1` is the equivalent to your `i + 1` step wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1;)
{
    c.Add(i);
    if (i < a.Length - 2 && a[i + 2] < a[i + 1])
        i += 2;
    else
        i += 1;
}
c.Add(a[a.Length - 1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ignored the possibility of future sums being effected by earlier choices.  I agree that is at some level of AI.

## Solution I revised to.

```
int total = 0;
cost += array[0];

int i = 0;
while (i < array.Length - 1)
{
    if ((array[i+1] + total) < array[i+2] + total) && (i != array.Length - 3))
    {
        total += array[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        total += array[i + 2];
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

I had to add the second to last element check because if the iterator landed on 2nd to last, there was no reason to check which one was lower as I had to pick the last one regardless.

Comment: How is that the solution? This is giving out of bounds exception because you check for `i < array.Length` and then access `array[i + 1]` and `array[i + 2]`.

Comment: Also, check the sequence `2, 1, 4, 7, 6`, I think your result (if not ending in exception) would be `13` with your approach but the correct result would be `12`.

Comment: @grek40  You are most correct, when checking i < array.Length, I missed that I changed that to i < array.Lenth - 1.

Comment: I am unsure how you are getting 12 on the array above.  I calculate it as 13 as well.  If you have to include 2 by default and 6, the path I would take would be 2, 1, 4, 6 = 13.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood, but why not go `2, 4, 6` is there a special rule requirement against this choice?

Comment: @grek40 That was my question from the start.  Technically that would get a lower score, but as I played with it more and more...it got into a level of what seemed like AI.  (Make choices early on based on future possible outcomes).  This was a basic puzzle and I do not believe it was supposed to be that advanced.  I was just making sure I didn't know about some neat trick to figure it out.  i.e. Binary search to improve array searches, and other techniques like that.  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Well maybe I have to expand my answer a bit... point is __do not make early choices__, there are cases where you need to know nearly the whole array in order to chose the first step to be taken (can be proven inductively, but I don't want to write that much into SO right now). However, the problem is __limited__ by the 1 or 2 size steps, so as I did in my answer, you can keep track of the best path to get somewhere, but technically speaking, you track both, the best path to the end and the best path to the next-to-last element. Sometimes they are the same path, sometimes they differ.